# How to associate user account to a domain user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm developing an *intranet site* project (`ASP.NET MVC` project).
How do I associate a user in a domain to its account (`UserAccount` entity):

```
public class UserAccount {
    // normally inherited from an abstract entity
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of "associate"?

Comment: And what do you mean with "set an account"? Remember, we have absolutely no more information about your problem than what you tell us here

Comment: See I can control whether user can access `Action methods/Controllers`. But (maybe I don't know something) the only bit of information about user is represented by its domain name. And I need to display something extra: dept., full name, post associated to this user. And again, using same domain account there could be many users so I also need to provide a password per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about how to query Active Directory to fetch a domain user details and populate the UserAccount class, you could use the following:

```
public UserAccount GetUserAccount(string username)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username))
    {
        return new UserAccount
        {
            Id = user.Guid,
            FullName = user.Name,
            Password = "FORGET ABOUT IT, YOU CAN'T RETRIEVE THE PASSWORD",
            EmployeeId = user.EmployeeId
        };
    }
}
```

But of course there's already an [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) that you could use if you are working with Windows Authentication.

Comment: Yes! This is what I want. Also I'm curious is this way user information gets gathered in Sharepoint intranet sites?

Comment: I have strictly no idea. I have never touched nor intend to touch SharePoint in my life.

Comment: SharePoint uses the User Profile Service which is using FIM under the covers to DirSync with AD.

Answer (score 1):

The `Guid` property maps to `objectGuid` in AD which is not going to change for the lifetime of a user inside the forest boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the [SAM-Account-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to refer to the user object in AD.

Comment: No. The `samAccountName` value is not remotely immutable.

Comment: @BrianDesmond - "remotely immutable" ?

Comment: Yes - it can change at any time. That value changes all the time in many organizations - consider someone who gets married.